# Specifying css selectors

Tags: css

I have a footer, which has a horizontal menu.

**CSS**

```
footer {
    height:99px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top:26px;
}
li {
    float:right;
    width:8%;
}
```

I want to make it so that when I make other menus, the css for the footer menu won't affect it. What would be an effective method for this? The html is just a basic `<footer>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can use descendant relationship, where you say apply the style to `ul` elements which comes inside a `footer` element.

```
footer {
    height:99px;
}
footer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top:26px;
}
footer ul li {
    float:right;
    width:8%;
}
```

If you want to be more specific(if you might have multiple footer elements in the page) you can assign a class to the footer like `myfooter` then use the class selector also like

```
footer.myfooter {
}
footer.myfooter ul {
}
footer.myfooter ul li {
}
```

Have a look st the different [CSS selctors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: An `id`, e.g., `#myFooter`, might be more appropriate than a class, since it applies to only one footer.